Have pressing the power button briefly immediately shutdown the laptop?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and I want even briefly pressing the power button to immediately shut down my laptop (preferrably even when the laptop is locked and the screen is off)
I have tried setting it in Settings > Power, modifying logind.conf with HandlePowerKey=poweroff and PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=yes, deleted logind.conf, now it's gone though, not coming back it seems. And using acpi
cat /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
event=button[ /]power
action=/sbin/poweroff

none of these seem to enable the power button to do anything when (briefly) pressed.
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
Acer Predator with nvidia 4080 16gb

Do you want it to go through a shutdown process or immediately turn off?

Immediately turn off? Well, having it trigger a hardware just by short press isn't possible I think? So the OS would obviously handle it and know, but I want it to shutdown "as quickly as possible"

WARNING - This will pull the power immediately. It won't even sync data to the disk first - forget about an orderly shutdown process.   When you touch that button the system is off.
Technically it goes through the kernel and OS, but it would be faster then a human can react.  You can do a full shutdown "in the blink of an eye" as follows -
Create a file /etc/acpi/events/power with the following
event=button/power
action=echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger

Then enable this with the command service acpid restart.
(You might want to have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for other options you can trigger)

similar to /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn not working, this also doesn't seem to work. something seems to be inhibiting the powerbutton to be picked up? it's all set in the gui settings, acpi and logind.conf, but something just inhibits the key from triggering anything

Is ACPID running?   Does issuing the command  "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger" as root from the command line bring the system down?   What version of the kernel are you using ("uname -a" will tell you this)


uname -a
Linux cnuuy-predator 6.8.0-38-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun  7 15:25:01 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

i'll try the command in a moment

I've just looked at it, and my system is still running "22.04" - so I'm running an older stock kernel -  6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC" -   Did issuing the command as root cause your system to reboot - Knowing this will help us deduce if its an issue with the kernel (if the command does not work), or ACPI monitoring if it does.  I guess its possible that the problem is in your UEFI, but I'd be a bit surprised as my UEFI is about as primitive as it gets - I have a cheap Chinese micropc as my desktop - as its adequate for my needs.

Oh right I forgot to answer after my pc shut down, "echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger" it does work. The Acer Predator UEFI does look a bit fancy imo, so maybe there is something to it, but I also didn't feel like any of the settings in there seemed relevant. I might note them down manually and show you just in case.

hitting the powerbutton is also not picked up by evtest it seems
